# How to cancel a PayPal reference transaction using api

Tags: c#, php, paypal

I am trying to cancel a PayPal reference transaction (I use PayPal's c# api). I tried using PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.DoVoid(), and PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus() with profile ID "B-3E365702...", but I get an error: "The profile ID is invalid". What API call can I use to cancel a reference transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cancel a reference transaction, you can only refund transactions.

It appears you actually want to cancel a billing agreement (which is something that's used to create reference transactions). How you cancel one will depend on the API used to create it. If you are using the classic NVP/SOAP API, then you are probably looking for [BAUpdate or METHOD=BillingAgreementUpdate](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ba-update-nvp/).

Since you mention a "c# api" you are likely using some SDK which would include a function that implements this.

Comment: PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.BillAgreementUpdate() works, thanks!